# Rails: How to invalidate all user sessions in all browsers on logout from one browser using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise gem for login/logout of the users. When a user logs in in two browsers, and then logs out from one of them, the other browser is still active. I want the user to be logged out in all browsers when they log out from one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Add a session_token column to your devise model (e.g. User) and override Devise #authenticatable_salt method to contain your session token:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord         
  def authenticatable_salt
    return super unless session_token

    "#{super}#{session_token}"
  end

  def invalidate_all_sessions!
    update_attribute(:session_token, SecureRandom.hex)
  end
end
```

You can now invalidate the session cookie by resetting the session_token of a user, when he/she logs out:

```rb
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def destroy
    current_user.invalidate_all_sessions!
    super
  end
end
```